# Transfering file from local to a linux system (java code) without using any 3rd party jar

Tags: java, file-transfer

I want to do some file transfer between my local system to a Linux server with Java code.
below functionality, I need to write

1. Connect to Linux server
2. Put file from Local to Linux server
3. Get file from Linux to local
4. Delete file in Linux server if exist

Note That I should not use any kind of 3rd party jar like `jsch`.

Previously I did this Job with the help of jsch jar and that was working very fine for me. But for my project, I should not use this 3rd party jar. So I need to perform the same task without the use of any 3rd party jar.

Comment: You can use SSH without an additional jar. What have you tried so far?

Comment: that's good for you. let us know how it works out

Comment: do ssh for connection and do scp for file copy and rm for deletion , as you need java code use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could help you, but if you can't use any libs, maybe go back to the basics.  Look into connecting through Sockets.

You will need a client module and a server module (One is installed on your local machine), and one is installed on your server module)

I suggest you google a lot and discuss with your teacher.

Comment: Please include some links with further reading. I know thequestion isquite broad, but you'd help the man out if you can point him in the right direction.